# Tkinter ImageTk - How to insert an image label into a frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So in this GUI I´m trying to insert my image (book.png) into a frame. The idea is that the red frame is in the top of the window with the image centered in it and the blue one below, empty. Here´s the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class MainApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        self.master=master
        super().__init__(self.master)

        #----------------master config------------------
        self.master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(self.master.winfo_screenwidth()-15, self.master.winfo_screenheight()-75))
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.master.iconbitmap("Book.ico")

        #----------------frame config------------------
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.fState=False

        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        MMenuFrame1=tk.Frame(self, bg="red").pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        MMenuFrame2=tk.Frame(self, bg="blue").pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.logo=Image.open("book.png")
        self.logo=self.logo.resize((150,150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.logo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.logo)
        self.mainMenuLogo=tk.Label(MMenuFrame1, image=self.logo)
        self.mainMenuLogo.pack(expand=False)
        self.mainMenuLogo.image=self.logo


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root=tk.Tk()
    app=MainApp(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

But when I run this it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6wHv.png):

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Order of packing(`widget.pack()`) is the issue here. You are packing the frames first and the label with image later, so you get that order. Change the order to get your desired output.

Comment: Your `MMenuFrame1` and `MMenuFrame2` variables are both `None` - the return value of `.pack()`, NOT the `Frame`s as you intended.  You need to do the geometry management as a separate statement if you want to keep references to the widgets.

Comment: @jasonharper brings up probably the root cause of your issue. But it would seem that you should also set `self.master` as your master for `MMenuFrame1` and `MMenuFrame2` rather than just `self`.

Comment: `self` as the master is correct. changing to `self.master` will make `root` as the master instead of `MainApp`